# Display dynamic form options in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google sheet named 'Data' where a user can enter their own product names and sale numbers associated with it (meant to be a template so the product names may change user to user). I have read in the data and the product names (PRODUCT_NAMES) into some global data objects so I have access to it. I have created a menu item called "Plot Data" which goes to function (for now) testFunction()

I would like to display a form to the user that displays a checkbox grid item of all their product names (and maybe more future options), based on which ones they check I create a graph or calculate some values.

My question is two part:
1) How to create a form with dynamic grid choices, say one user has

```
PRODUCT_NAMES = {"Shirt", "Pants", "Shoes"}
```

and another has

```
PRODUCT_NAMES = {"Cars", "Trucks", "Suvs", "Trailers", "Boats"}
```

2) How to display the form in a google sheet? I have right now:

```
function testFunction() {
  // Create a new form since the options change
  var form = FormApp.create('Test Form');
  var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
  item.setTitle("This is a Test");
  // TODO: Add dynamic options here
  var formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formUrl);
  var formHtml = response.GetContextText();

  var htmlApp = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutput(formHtml)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Sales Data')
      .setWidth(500) 
      .setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlApp);
}
```

But this does not seem to work, I may be misunderstanding something
Question 2b) How to access the user responses.

I am learning javascript and GAS on the fly, so this is all new to me. I would like to try and keep the user options part as a Google Form, just cause its easier from an API perspective what is going on.

Comment: It might be better to show a Modal with a basic HTML Form. Whoops, wrong link, **Updated:** https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface-title This keeps the code within the script itself.

Comment: @ChrisW I was looking at that, however as I an new to javascript and know nothing of HTML I couldnt figure out how to add drop downs, check boxes, and all the other nice features of Google Forms, which is why (for now) I am stuck on getting Google Forms to work.

Comment: @userr6768079 Okay! It was just a suggestion, though If you plan on continue working with Javascript you might as well take the plunge. Javascript and HTML are almost always used together. There are also countless tutorials and examples on HTML.

Comment: you have the following errors in the code, its `form.addCheckboxItem();` (it is small letter b i.e. box, not Box). Secondly,  its `item.setTitle()` (set, not Set)

Answer (score 0):

From my comment, expanded a bit, for future users:

It would be better to show a [UI Modal Dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface-title) with a basic HTML form. This keeps the code within the script itself.

The issue with what you want to do is once the form is made and the spreadsheet is linked the data will still go to a new sheet **per form**, not to where you want it to go, *and* then you'd have to setup a `onEdit()` trigger to get the values from the new sheet, generate charts, then delete the sheet and, somehow, the form. It is possible, but probably more work than a simple Modal Dialog.

Consider the HTML option as there are numerous simple-to-follow tutorials and examples and resources on the web. If you do end up trying it out, I'd suggest [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) to start!

Good luck either way!